# Is possible node.js interaction with JMS queue?

Tags: node.js, jms

Is possible node.js interaction with JMS queue ?  Context I need to implement a solution that needs a JMS and node to work, a can make a communication happen via java, but I want to know if it is possible to do it via node directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question will depend on which JMS broker you use. If your JMS broker also supports STOMP then you can use the [node-stomp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-stomp) client. For example, both the [ActiveMQ 5.x](http://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/) and [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) brokers support STOMP & JMS.